# Hardcode function value if function is false in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hardcoded

I want to return the function value as a paste special value if the function is false (like a hard coded answer). Can anyone help me please? 
I thought it was easier to use function instead of sub, because i have to do this to a fairly big data set.

```
Function produktion(d2, sum1, sum2)

    Dim j As Integer
    j = Application.Sum(sum1) - Application.Sum(sum2)


    If d2 = Date Then

        produktion = j

    Else
        'here hardcode the produktion = j forever like the paste special value
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I'm confused on the question.  Return a paste special value?  Are you trying to reformat the column when d2 isn't a date?  Right now it appears to be returning results of a subtraction, not a conditional expression?

Comment: Please define what you mean by a **paste-special value**.  I don't see that in the list of the data types that a Function may return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UDF cannot directly modify a worksheet, it can only return a value.  There are work arounds that trigger code to execute outside the UDF call itself.

One such is to use `Evaluate` to call the code that modifies the sheet (another is to use worksheet events as Gary answered)

```
Function produktion(d2, sum1, sum2)
    Dim j As Long
    j = Application.Sum(sum1) - Application.Sum(sum2)

    If d2 = Date Then
        produktion = j
    Else
        With Application.Caller
            'here hardcode the produktion = j forever like the paste special value
            .Worksheet.Evaluate "HardCodeValue(""" & .Address & """)"
        End With
    End If
End Function

Sub HardCodeValue(rng As String)
    With Range(rng)
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In a standard module enter:

```
Public FreezeWho As String
Public FreezeNow As Boolean

Public Function produktion(d2 As Date, sum1 As Range, sum2 As Range) As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, j As Long
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    j = wf.Sum(sum1) - wf.Sum(sum2)
    produktion = j
    If d2 = Date Then
        FreezeWho = Application.Caller.Address
        FreezeNow = True
    End If
End Function
```

and in the worksheet code area enter:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If FreezeNow Then
        Range(FreezeWho).Value = Range(FreezeWho).Value
        FreezeNow = False
    End If
End Sub
```

When the *"freeze"* condition is *True.* the function signals the event macro.  The event macro sees the signal and freezes the cell containing the function.